# Contact Form 7: use hook created using wpcf7_before_send_mail for only one contact form by id

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working on a site with several forms created using Contact Form 7.  For one of these forms, I am passing variables that I collected using a hidden input field in the form.  I am passing these variables into the email using the wpcf7_before_send_mail hook, but these values are passing into every email (I added dynamic variables as well as static text) Here's the code:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body' );

 function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body($contact_form){
     $values_list = $_POST['valsitems'];
     $values_str = implode(", ", $values_list);

     // get mail property
     $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' ); // returns array 

     // add content to email body
     $mail['body'] .= 'INDUSTRIES SELECTED';
     $mail['body'] .= $values_list;


     // set mail property with changed value(s)
     $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );

 }
```

I am trying to figure out how to only pass these values to one of the contact form email templates, probably via the form id.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Contact Form 7 uses hidden input type to store form id. It uses hidden field name **_wpcf7**. You can get the form Id like this way.

```
$form_id = $contact_form->posted_data['_wpcf7'];
```

So you final code should be

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body' );

function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body($contact_form){
 $form_id = $contact_form->posted_data['_wpcf7'];
 if ($form_id == 123): // 123 => Your Form ID.
     $values_list = $_POST['valsitems'];
     $values_str = implode(", ", $values_list);

     // get mail property
     $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' ); // returns array 

     // add content to email body
     $mail['body'] .= 'INDUSTRIES SELECTED';
     $mail['body'] .= $values_list;


     // set mail property with changed value(s)
     $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );
 endif;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use `$contact_form->id()` to get the form id

Comment: This won't work because `$posted_data` is not a property of [`WPCF7_ContactForm`](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/contact-form.php) (anymore?). Use the third argument supplied to the action hook instead to access "posted data", which contains the class [`WPCF7_Submission`](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/submission.php). This class contains the method [`get_posted_data($name = null)`](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/submission.php#L197) what you can use instead.

Answer (score 16):

The methods for retrieving the form ID and submitted fields have changed in this plugin since 2015, and [again in 2020](https://contactform7.com/2020/07/28/accessing-user-input-data/) since writing this answer.

To get the form ID, you should use this:

```
$form_id = $contact_form->id();
```

To get the submission data you should use this (instead of $_POST). The function `get_posted_data()` returns a string (if you supplied a key to pull specifically) or an array of string values (if no parameters are sent and you want everything).

```
$posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
```

To put it all together, your snippet would look like this:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body', 10, 3 );
function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {

    //Get the form ID
    $form_id = $contact_form->id();

    //Do something specifically for form with the ID "123"
    if( $form_id == 123 ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $values_list = $posted_data['valsitems'];
        $values_str = implode(", ", $values_list);

        // get mail property
        $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' ); // returns array 

        // add content to email body
        $mail['body'] .= 'INDUSTRIES SELECTED';
        $mail['body'] .= $values_list;

        // set mail property with changed value(s)
        $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );
    }
}
```

Below is the original snippet I wrote in this answer and can be used for older versions of Contact Form 7 that do not pass the `$submission` variable.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body', 10, 1 );
function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body( $contact_form ) {

    //Get the form ID
    $form_id = $contact_form->id();

    //Do something specifically for form with the ID "123"
    if( $form_id == 123 ) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();//Get the current form submission
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $values_list = $posted_data['valsitems'];
        $values_str = implode(", ", $values_list);

        // get mail property
        $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' ); // returns array 

        // add content to email body
        $mail['body'] .= 'INDUSTRIES SELECTED';
        $mail['body'] .= $values_list;

        // set mail property with changed value(s)
        $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a [look at my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533216/#comment119410776_30694477). `WPCF7_Submission` is supplied as the third argument of the action hook.

Comment: @luukvhoudt Thank you. I've updated my answer to include that third argument after having found the updated documentation on contact form 7's website that was published about 7 months after my answer here :)

Comment: You're not supplying the 3rd and 4th arguments to the `add_action` function for the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook. You should at least set the 4th argument to `3`, otherwise you will get a PHP warning if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to add that part. You're correct since the default value for the 4th parameter is `1` and we definitely want to change that to a `3` with the CF7 update.

Answer (score 11):

I was using Dinesh's answer, but it stopped working for me.  Instead, I am now checking for a field that is unique to the form I'm submitting:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body' );
function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body($contact_form){

   $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
   $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
   if( !empty($posted_data["dealer_email"])){  //use a field unique to your form

       $email = trim($posted_data["dealer_email"]);
       // more custom stuff here
   }
}
```

Be sure to have at least one unique form name in each of your forms that you can use to do this. It might still be possible to get the form ID from $contact_form via a function, but this worked and I was content with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly changed the great answer be @Tessa
because it just didn't work for me. It appears that
a slightly different structure is needed to inject
a different email address.

**Hope this helps anyone.**

```
/********************************************************
**  IF COUNTRY == USA && ON CONTACT US PAGE 
**  USE A DIFFERENT RECIPIENT EMAIL
********************************************************/
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body', 10, 3 );
function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {

    //Get the form ID
    $form_id    = $contact_form->id();
    $new_email  = 'example@example.com';        // change email here

    // checking if this if a specific form by its ID
    if( $form_id == 572 ) {

        $posted_data    = $submission->get_posted_data();

        
        // i only changed the email is a select field named country was set to USA..
        if(!empty($posted_data['country'][0]) && $posted_data['country'][0] == 'United States') {

            // set mail property with changed value(s)
            $mailProp = $contact_form->get_properties('mail');
            $mailProp['mail']['recipient'] = $new_email;
            $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mailProp['mail'] ) );

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question, however, if you didn't want to hardcode your email address in this function but send it from a pre-filled form field, you could use `$new_email = $submission->get_posted_data( 'your-email' );`. But yes, the `recipient` key in the `mail` array is where you want to put it, not in the `body` (which is where OP was asking)