# How to perform custom Javascript logic only after Contact Form 7 validates?

Tags: wordpress

I need to send some of the data from my WordPress Contact Form 7 form to an external API. I can do this via Javascript but only want to do so IF and ONLY IF the data validates AND PRIOR TO the mail getting sent. The reason I need to access the external API prior to the email sending is because the API has its own validation that needs to pass and I need to be able to communicate back to the user. So in essence the logic flow needs to be:

- Validate Contact Form 7
- Validate external API
- Send email confirmation

According to their docs, I can perform custom Javascript logic on Contact Form 7 submit OR sent, but not in between which is what I need to do.

From the docs:

http://contactform7.com/additional-settings/

```
on_sent_ok: "alert('sent ok');"
on_submit: "alert('submit');"
```

> If you set on_sent_ok: followed by a one-line JavaScript code, you can tell the contact form the code that should be performed when the mail is sent successfully. Likewise, with on_submit:, you can tell the code that should be performed when the form submitted regardless of the outcome.

Comment: Does the API access need to be done in JavaScript?  Or can it be done in PHP on the server?

Comment: use "wpcf7_before_send_mail" hook to check validations before mail send

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533216/contact-form-7-use-hook-created-using-wpcf7-before-send-mail-for-only-one-conta

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. However, I decided to forego the usage of Contact Form 7 altogether. I'm now using the jQuery Validation library in tandem with the 3rd party API to handle my form. I'll write custom PHP code to do the back end processing.