# How to use Contact Form 7 along with Accordion?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am stuck at one point with using contact form 7 along with accordion and don't know how can i do so ??

Please see the attached screenshot for more details like what i want to achieve ...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally after struggling for 3 and half day finally i found way to do so..sharing stuffs for others who are willing to do so ..

For repetition stuffs (use this) :

https://www.craftblue.com/projects/jquery/form-element-repeater-plugin/

For mailing :

[Contact Form 7: use hook created using wpcf7_before_send_mail for only one contact form by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533216/contact-form-7-use-hook-created-using-wpcf7-before-send-mail-for-only-one-conta)

Hope this will help others also...

Cheers...