# Contact form 7 hooks not working at all - New Version

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to execute some `PHP` script with `contact form 7` but none of the hooks working. I am using a new version of wordpress, contact form plugin. Tried `wpcf7_before_send_mail` and `wpcf7_mail_sent`

**Sample code in functions.php file:**

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','_wpcf7_mail_sent_function');
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', '_wpcf7_mail_sent_function'); 

function _wpcf7_mail_sent_function( $contact_form ) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();  
    error_log("test");
    wp_mail('-----------@gmail.com', 'contact form 7', 'Hooks not working');
    print_r( $submission);
    
    die;
}
```

Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check this thread and then check both hooks again.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533216/contact-form-7-use-hook-created-using-wpcf7-before-send-mail-for-only-one-conta

Comment: Already checked this, both hooks are not firing.

Comment: Then must doubt on your wp_mail function because sometimes it happens that mail functions are not working.

Comment: @WordPressMechanic Mail function working fine, and same time I am using wpcf7_before_send_mail but this hook not working as well

Comment: Try switching `die` to `return` - additionally, you won't be able to `print_r` your output.

Comment: @HowardE I tried everything and no luck. I am not sure what was the issue. Got issue after website updates

Comment: Can you try this function https://gist.github.com/DuckDivers/cbb7acb489cae29df8c215c9691bb0f6 and see if you get any output from your form?

Comment: @HowardE Strange things happing, not working

Comment: Is this a development environment? Can you disable all other plugins and revert to a default theme and try again. Either your error log is disabled or something else is conflicting with contact form 7. My debug to error log definitely works.

Comment: This is the issue on the Live site, but I've set up a development environment to fix the issue.

Comment: The other way to debug contact form 7 output is to use the Query Monitor plugin and Kint Debugger.  You would disable the JS submission on CF7. `add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );` then you can debug the submissions on that page with a similar function as my Gist, but instead of error_log, just use d($posted_data);

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have changed the priority of the action hook to 4 and set the number of parameters to 1. I have also changed the code slightly, so that you may see more data in the var_dump.

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', '_wpcf7_mail_sent_function', 4, 1);

function _wpcf7_mail_sent_function( $contact_form ) {
    $title = $contact_form->title();
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $postedData = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $formID = $contact_form->id();
    error_log("test");
    wp_mail('-----------@gmail.com', 'contact form 7', 'Hooks not working');
    var_dump($title, $submission, $postedData, $formID);
    
    die;
}
```